# Is causal relationship between two variables a theory?

Tags: causality, mathematical-statistics, research-design

I was asked if Y causes Z a theory, and I noticed that I have a gap in my knowledge on that. I know that theory could be causal, descriptive or predictive in its explanation. However, a theory is an extensive and systematic explanation of a causal relationship between two variables. So, only saying Y causes Z is more like an alternative hypothesis rather than a theory. I would be really grateful if clarify that.

Thank you all.

Comment: It is difficult to prove causation. Easier to establish correlation or to show that one variable can be used to predict another. Cold weather might cause icy road conditions, leading to lots of car accidents. Cold weather might cause higher heating bills. So you might have some success using accident rate as an aid in predicting heating bills. But it would be quite a stretch of logic to conclude that car accidents cause high heating bills. // What then is your specific _statistical_ question?